# SASS installation with Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, dependencies

I ran 
npm install  --save-dev to install dev dependencies, which finished  successfully but why there is no entry shown in package.json related to this command.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that if I removed "-g" option from the command

npm install -g grunt --save-dev it works properly -

so basically removing the global option from the command it is updating the package.json correctly.

Comment: `npm install -g grunt --save-dev` installs grunt globally, and adds it to package.json. You only need to do `npm install -g grunt` once, then do `npm install grunt --save-dev` for each new project.